# Android app cannot connect to internet when try to run automate testing using TestDroid

Tags: java, android, testing, automated-tests, testdroid

I'm trying to record my activity in Android application using TestDroid Recorder.

My app need internet to run. And it run perfectly before I use TestDroid Recorder.
But I don't know why my app cannot connect to internet when I try to record it.

Someone said that I must setting "Internet permission in your manifest"
But I don't know how to do that? Can someone tell me what should I do?

Or why my app suddenly cannot connect to internet when I want to record it using TestDroid?
thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to run it? Do you get an error? Post your logcat.

Comment: I try to record my activity, but my apk didn't want to load.. This is my apk fault or what? :(

Answer (score 0):

add this inside your manifest xml tag

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: in testdroid, first we must record our activity on apk then we can see our code automatically generated.. when I must insert that code? after recording activity?

but I my apk didn't want to open...

*poor english. sorry... :(